# how to set the second line identation ie., W.P NO. using open source apache poi in java?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

[image]

```
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();
        tmpParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        tmpRun.setText("<<highcourt>>");
        tmpRun.setFontSize(18);
        XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph1 = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun tmpRun1 = tmpParagraph1.createRun();
        tmpParagraph1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
        tmpRun1.setText("W.P NO.");
        tmpRun1.setFontSize(18);
        tmpParagraph1.setIndentationLeft(85);
```

Comment: How would you do that using `Word`'s GUI? Could be either a table or tab stops used.